# How to randomize in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to randomize what text shows on a page in PHP.

I'm sure this is very easy but everything I search for related to this is talking about the shuffle() function - which isn't what I want to do.

I want half the time people go to my page for them to see "This is a test 1" and the other half of the time they should see "This is a test 2".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like this: `echo ['This is a test 1', 'This is a test 2'][mt_rand(0,1)];`

Comment: http://php.net/rand `rand(1,2)`

Comment: Have you tried to do anything?

Comment: Seriously though, shouldn't this just get flagged since the answer would have ben found easily if he had just googled it.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

I guess you mean `pseudo-random` when using PHP functions.

Also take a look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

```
<?php
    $texts = array("a", "b", "c");
    echo $texts[array_rand($texts, 1)]; // Output: a, b or c
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kuOWNI

### Extra

`I want half the time people go to my page for them to see "This is a test 1" and the other half of the time they should see "This is a test 2".`

This means, you don't want random. Because when you use true-random it can happen that the output is `This is a test 1` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just shuffle it.:

```
$page = rand(1, 2);

if($page=='1'){
   $website = 'http:/xxxxxx.xxx/';
 }else{
   $website = 'http:/xxxxxx.xxx/';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your text in an array, then select a random item from the array using any of a variety of functions.

```
<?php

$text = array(
    "This is a test",
    "This is another test"
);

print $text[mt_rand(0,count($text)-1)];
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Vf5oe5

I used `count($text)` so that if you want to add a third option, you can just add it to the array and not have to worry about further code changes.  We `-1` from the `count()` because array keys are numbered from zero.

**UPDATE**

As Bondye correctly pointed out, you are not asking for *random*, you are asking for *balanced*.  For that, you'd need to store something on your server, perhaps a toggle or a count, and update that record every time the page is viewed.  If this is what you need, you might want to re-frame your question, and provide further detail about what you've attempted so far, along with your server environment (and the back-end database you're using).

Comment: So you use `count()` to know the length and with that you use `mt_rand()` to get the random key? Isn't this what `array_rand()` does?

Comment: Actually, not quite.  `array_rand()` uses libc, which is slower and not as random than Mersenne Twister generator.